# Can't switch between 2 view controller's with a Segmented Control

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uisegmentedcontrol

I created a UISegmentedControl programmatically in the navigation bar of a UIViewController and I want to be able to switch view controllers when i toggle the segmented control.

This is what I have so far:

```
 @interface TVExploreViewController : TVViewController

    @property (nonatomic, strong) UISegmentedControl *scopeControl;
    @property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger scope;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) UIViewController *premiumContentViewController;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) UIViewController *trendingContentViewController;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) UIViewController *currentViewController;

 @end
```

TVExploreViewController's implementation:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
      [super viewDidLoad];
      _scopeControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"TV & MOVIES", @"VIRAL CLIPS", nil]];
      [_scopeControl setFrame:CGRectMake(80, 0, 200, 30)];
      [_scopeControl addTarget:self
                     action:@selector(scopeChanged:)
                     forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
      [[self navigationItem] setTitleView:_scopeControl];
      [_scopeControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:0];

      _premiumContentViewController = [[TVPremiumContentViewController alloc] init];
      _trendingContentViewController = [[TVTrendingFeedController alloc] init];
      [self setScope:0];
}

- (void)scopeChanged:(id)sender {
    [self setScope:self.scopeControl.selectedSegmentIndex];
}

- (void)transitionToViewController:(UIViewController *)controller
{
    [self.currentViewController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    if (controller) {
        [self addChildViewController:controller];
    }

    controller.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [self.view addSubview:controller.view];
    [self.currentViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self.currentViewController removeFromParentViewController];
    [controller didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    self.currentViewController = controller;
}

- (void)setScope:(NSInteger)scope {
    if (scope != _scope) {
        _scope = scope;
        UIViewController *nextController = nil;

        if (_scope == 0) {
            nextController = self.premiumContentViewController;
        } else if (_scope == 1) {
            nextController = self.trendingContentViewController;
        }
        [self transitionToViewController:nextController];
    }
}
```

When I toggle the segmented control in TVExploreViewController, the rest of the view stays white and no view controller is loaded. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What code is supposed to be invoked when the user changes the selected segment in your segmented control? You need an IBAction connected to the  UIControlEventValueChanged event for the segmented control, and you did not show ANY IBAction code at all.

Comment: I have this in the viewDidLoad: `[_scopeControl addTarget:self
                     action:@selector(scopeChanged:)
                     forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];`

Comment: @DuncanC you don't have to use interface builder to create a control...

Comment: @John that's true, but you do need an action method that it connects to. Oh, now I see. He's got code that adds a segmented control manually, and adds a target/action using the method scopeChanged:. When I didn't see an IBAction I stopped looking. My mistake.

Comment: @thiscrazy4, did you set a breakpoint in your setScope method and make sure it's being called?

Comment: @thiscrazy4, I strongly suggest making your action methods use the keyword IBAction even if you don't create the control using IB. It makes your intent for that method very clear. It also makes it trivial to hook the control to the action in IB at some future date if you later need to do so.

Comment: @DuncanC Yes, I stepped through the code and everything is getting called appropriately, but no view controllers are shown.

Comment: I'd have to disagree with that above comment -- following Cocoa naming conventions should be enough to understand what actions are being performed to invoke the method and IBAction is just compiler sugar to let you know what methods are handled automagically by IB. But this is not the place for that discussion, and I'm on an iPhone right now, so.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but It is convenient to write some log code here.

Can you show me the log in the method ?

```
- (void)transitionToViewController:(UIViewController *)controller
{
    [self.currentViewController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    if (controller) {
        [self addChildViewController:controller];
    }

    controller.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [self.view addSubview:controller.view];
    [self.currentViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self.currentViewController removeFromParentViewController];
    [controller didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    self.currentViewController = controller;

    // can you show me the log here ?
    NSLog(@"%@, %@, %@", controller.view, controller.view.superview, self.view) ;
    // you should see the subviews that you added.
    NSLog(@"subviews:%@", [controller.view subviews]) ;
}
```

Comment: <UIView: 0x1493e4c0; frame = (0 0; 320 480); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x14921a50>>, <UIView: 0xd8b1f40; frame = (0 0; 320 480); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0xd8b1fa0>>, <UIView: 0xd8b1f40; frame = (0 0; 320 480); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0xd8b1fa0>>

Comment: @thisiscrazy4 controller.view is added in the hierarchy. It seems that the problem is in TVTrendingFeedController or TVTrendingFeedController.

Comment: Any idea what the problem could be? They seem to be working fine if I load them individually.

Comment: @thisiscrazy4 I am not sure. How do you config `TVTrendingFeedController` or `TVPremiumContentViewController`? xib or add controls manually in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: One thing I just noticed..if i set the background color of self.view of TVExploreViewController to some non-white color, it remains white. Is that normal?

Comment: @thisiscrazy4 Because self.view of TVExploreViewController is coverd with its subView. Have a try to change background color([UIColor redColor]) in TVTrendingFeedController or TVPremiumContentViewController `viewDidLoad`. I wonder why you can't see your controls added in TVTrendingFeedController or TVPremiumContentViewController `viewDidLoad` method, what do you add in `viewDidLoad` ?

Comment: Just did, and it remained white. Then I tried allocating just a UIViewController instead of TVTrendingFeedController, changed its background color and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It is really not a good idea to add Viewcontrollers to ViewController,you should always have one ViewController on screen. You could do this using NavigationController with pushing with no animation.